# How to regain my voice

Tags: voice, tenor

I've been a great singer since school but took a year long break now every time I sing with full fledged voice  it feels hoarse after and I can't sing well after that for a day ,my voice durability was far superior before the break 
Also I suffered reflux  esophagitis  and pharyngitis during the break :( 
Any idea what I can do to regain my voice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best is and always will be conversation with a professional tutor.
I can offer one bit of advice though: sirens.
Starting on a note you can sing comfortably and taking up slowly until it becomes difficult is a safe way to see where you're at. But don't... force anything. If your voice has been through the wars you should stay to your comfort zone until said zone begins to expand naturally.

Comment: Thank you so much have been following that for the moment sticking to a very comfortable zone for my present shows..   Hoping improvement arrives

Answer (score 0):

Like for all practice, it is important to not overdo it. There might be other complications in your specific case, but the obvious suggestions are to not strain the voice and sing for shorter durations. Accept that "full fledged" now isn't as powerful as it was before. Best course of action is probably to go to a professional teacher and get some suggestions, especially since you've had some medical conditions.

Comment: Is it possible that this medical conditions have permanently hindered my singing capability?

Comment: It is certainly possible, so it is important to ask someone with professional knowledge with these issues, like a doctor or a voice specialist before trying too hard, and possibly make things worse.

Comment: Thank you so much...  I live in India n a voice specialist or something of the sort is not easily found or at disposal but I'll try...    Won't ever give up of course